# How to navigate to a UITableView position by the cell it's title using indexing

Tags: iphone, uitableview, indexing

I'm using a UITableView filled with a around 200 cells containing a title, subtitle and thumbnail image. I want to a have a selection method just like within the contact App from Apple where you can select a character from the alphabet.

I'm at the point where I've drawn the selection interface (A,B,C etc), and via it's delegate I'm retrieving the respective index and title (i.e: A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 etc.).

Now I want to navigate to the first cell, where the first character of the cell it's title is starting with the selected index character.  Just like the contacts App.

Can someone give me a direction for how to implement such functionality.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

I filled my sectionIndex by means of

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if(searching)
        return nil;

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:@"A"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"B"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"C"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"D"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"E"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"F"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"G"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"H"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"I"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"J"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"K"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"L"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"M"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"N"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"O"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"P"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Q"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"R"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"S"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"T"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"U"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"V"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"W"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"X"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Y"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Z"];

    return tempArray;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify better what it is you're attempting to do?  Your question is incredibly unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableView data source and delegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [contactArr count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    /*
     If the requesting table view is the search display controller's table view, return the count of the filtered list, otherwise return the count of the main list.
     */
        return [[[contactArr objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"name"] count];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0f;
}

#pragma mark -

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return [[contactArr objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"char"];

}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:@"A"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"B"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"C"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"D"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"E"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"F"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"G"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"H"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"I"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"J"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"K"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"L"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"M"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"N"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"O"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"P"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Q"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"R"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"S"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"T"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"U"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"V"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"W"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"X"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Y"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Z"];

    return tempArray;
//    return [[NSArray arrayWithObject:UITableViewIndexSearch] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:
//            tempArray];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
//  if (title == UITableViewIndexSearch) {
//            [tableView scrollRectToVisible:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame animated:NO];
//            return -1;
//        } else {
            return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];

}
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for. I only had to seperate my placed data so that I had 26 different sections!